# ej chart syncfusion access chart properties in controller c#

Tags: javascript, c#, charts, syncfusion

I have a grid and a chart. I need to export the grid (working now) into excel but include the chart as well.

so I use the grid export excel method and pass the chart (along with other params) as data like this:

var data = {
                    "ClientID":  $scope.Model.ClientID,
                   ....
                    "Chart": JSON.stringify($("#MyChart").ejChart("instance"), getCircularReplacer()) 
                };

```
  var grid = $("#" + table).ejGrid("instance");
    grid.export(url);
```

and It is passed to controller as string so I can convert it to chartproperties

```
[System.Web.Http.ActionName("ExcelExport")]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
        {
string EJChart = _dictParams["Chart"].ToString();

ChartProperties cprop = MyGridHelper.ConvertChartObject(EJChart);
}
```

code for convertchart object which I took from [here](https://help.syncfusion.com/js/chart/exporting):

After conversion, when I try to look for the series, legends, points which I needed to draw my chart in c#, all have no values. It seems it's not getting it using that converter.

so dig around a bit and see that those are inside model (one of the items in json EJChart) but it keeps saying cannot convert null, so I added null handler which it skips the item which made it even more null for values.

Bottomline:
How can I get the properties and values of the chart using c# from js controller but using grid export and not chart export? The sample code assumes that the export will be ejchart, but I am trying to export ejgrid along with the chart so I had to pass it as data params.

why is the converter not working in getting the values, but I can see it in the json passed as param which look like this:

```
{"dragSettings":{"enable":false,"type":"xy"},"type":"column","splitMode":"value","splitValue":null,"splineType":"natural","cardinalSplineTension":0.5,"gapWidth":50,"pieOfPieCoefficient":0.6,"visibleOnLegend":"visible","enableAnimation":false,"animationDuration":null,"animationType":"linear","isClosed":true,"isTransposed":false,"isStacking":false,"columnWidth":0.7,"columnSpacing":0,"columnFacet":"rectangle","drawType":"line","doughnutCoefficient":0.4,"explodeOffset":25,"pyramidMode":"linear","boxPlotMode":"exclusive","funnelWidth":"11.6%","funnelHeight":"32.7%","positiveFill":null,"showMedian":true,"outlierSettings":{"shape":"circle","size":{"width":6,"height":6}},"cornerRadius":{"topLeft":0,"topRight":0,"bottomLeft":0,"bottomRight":0},"connectorLine":{"width":1,"opacity":1,"dashArray":null,"color":"#565656"},"errorBar":{"visibility":"hidden","mode":"vertical","type":"fixedValue","horizontalErrorValue":1,"verticalErrorValue":3,"horizontalPositiveErrorValue":1,"horizontalNegativeErrorValue":1,"verticalPositiveErrorValue":5,"verticalNegativeErrorValue":5,"direction":"both","cap":{"visible":true,"width":1,"length":20,"fill":"#000000"},"width":1,"opacity":1,"fill":"#000000"}
```

also, upon debugging, I saw the series, points etc are inside model in EJChart.

Comment: I figured it out. not exactly the answer to my question but a better way. I just copied the img stream from UI. the code was from here https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/5045/how-to-export-the-chart . I was able to pass it in the excel export along with the grid by simply adding it as data in the params.  var data = {
                                        "Chart2": chartData,
                };  excelExport(url,data);  in this way I dont have to rebuild the chart in C#, instead just pass the img stream. the chart will be displayed in excel as img.

Answer (score 0):

We have prepared a sample as for your requirement using ajax. We have converting Chart object to json string and passed to controller via AJAX. Before converting json, you have to set chart.model.event  to null. This event API is used for internal purpose. Now we can get the chart properties with this JSON using convertchart method.

Please find the code snippet below to set null for event.

```
    var chart = $("#ChartObject").ejChart("instance"); 
    chart.model.event = null; 
    var chartJson = JSON.stringify(chart.model);
```

Sample for your reference can be find from below link, 
 http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/202840/ze/export-1342070198 
Please revert us, if you have any concern.

Thanks,

Baby.

Comment: I was able to make this work using the same code but I came upon an issue in the stringify where it says circular error, so I had to create a method  const getCircularReplacer = () => {
        const seen = new WeakSet;
        return (key, value) => {
            if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
                if (seen.has(value)) {
                    return;
                }
                seen.add(value);
            }
            return value;
        };
    }; works great in chrome but doesn't work in IE.